# Regex: Match tags that contains diacritics and symbols

Tags: regex

I have this meta tag:

`<meta name="description" content="Measure you passion fort &acirc;rt in the name of ÖmÈ™r"/>`

So I write a good regex to find all meta tags description that contains diacritics/symbols:

`<meta name="description".*[ÖÈ™;#&Ã®ÃŽ]+.*?>`

My problem is that are too many symbols and diacritics in the word. I should add hundreds in square brackets.

My question: is there any short version for those too many diacritics and symbols? I need a formula that replace all symbols from brackets.

Comment: Your answer is probably highly tool/language dependent.  That being said, what language/tool are you using for your regex work?

Comment: notepad++, windows 10

Comment: To clarify: Are you trying to find `<meta>` tags that these symbols appear in  _anywhere_, or in a certain place?  E.g. are you looking in the `content` attribute for these symbols?

Comment: yes, I am looking in the `content` from just meta-description tag :)

Comment: `that replace all symbols from brackets` ... you can't replace anything, because you need a replacement for that, and you never told us what this replacement is.  Do you want to just remove all symbols?  This sounds like a bad idea. Also, you should tell us which symbols you want to replace.

Comment: *"I need a formula that replace..."*: to what do you want to replace them?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, are you asking me?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the following regex to match the `<meta>` tags which contain diacritics/symbols in their `content` attribute:

```
^<meta name=".*?" content=".*(?=[ÖÈ™#&Ã®ÃŽ]).*?".*>$
```

If you have never used find/replace in Notepad++ in regex mode, then now is the time to learn.  The find and replace dialogs have an option to do the find/replacement in regex mode, so you should select this option.  Rather than giving you screen captures from Notepad++, a simple demo of the regex might be more useful, q.v. the link below.

**Demo here:**

## Regex101

The only part of the regex which might be a bit confusing is the positive lookahead (assertion) which checks for presence of a diacritic/symbol in the `content` attribute:

```
content="            match content="
.*                   match any number/type of characters
(?=[ÖÈ™#&Ã®ÃŽ])      assert that at some point inside content, a diacritic/symbol
                     occurs once
.*?"                 again match any number/type of characters,
                     until the first closing quote
```

Comment: First of all  your regex does not match another case `<meta name="description"  asfas &acirc;rt >`

Besides, you have the same symbols like I made `[ÖÈ™#&Ã®ÃŽ]`. You don't understand, Tim. I need a formula that replace all symbols from brackets.

Comment: `So I write a good regex to find all meta tags` .. the word `replace` appears _nowhere_ in your question.  _You_ need to learn how to ask a question.  Update your question with what you really need.